# Instagram How can I get a permission in sandbox mode

Tags: instagram

I want to test my app by using Instagram API.

When I use tag API, I got a error message that

```
{
    "meta": {
        "error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException",
        "code": 400,
        "error_message": "This request requires scope=public_content, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=public_content to be granted this permissions."
    }
}
```

Users in sandbox mode can use all API, I'm also in sandbox mode. But I can't use tag API.

What is the problem with this?

Comment: can you put the url which you use for the login? The problem might be there

Comment: Well.. actually we have the domain, but we don't have web site by using domain. this could be the problem? my url is http://www.utf4you.com

Comment: At some point you will be calling some url like https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=##YOUR_CLIENT_ID##&redirect_uri=http://utf4you.com/&response_type=code . Double check that that redirect url is the same one that appears in your app page under instagram.com .